# Why I can't use this program in a second way

Tags: java, static, byte, non-static

```
String word = "coding";

/*first way*/
byte[] code = word.getBytes();

/*second way*/
byte[] code2 = String.getBytes(word);
```

Could someone explain me why I can't declare my byte array with the second way.
What is the difference between two of them?

Comment: maybe because the String class doesn't have a static getBytes method?

Comment: why do you need another way?

Comment: so i could only use the second way, if getBytes method was a static?

Comment: @ŁukaszKrzyżakFranczyk, no, if it was a static, it would be possible to use this method on instances too

Comment: @DavidWallace, what exactly is correct?

Comment: Thank you guys for your responses :)

Answer (score 2):

> Could someone explain me why I can't declare my byte array with the second way?

You cannot use the second way because there is no static method with a name `getBytes` in the `String` class.

But if the second way is necessary, you could write own variant:

```
public static byte[] getBytes(String s) {
    return s.getBytes();
}
```

> What is the difference between two of them?

- `instance.getBytes()` exists, is a non-static method, doesn't take any parameters
- `String.getBytes(String s)` is a `static` method, takes 1 `String` parameter, doesn't exist.

---

It seems you don't understand the difference between static and non-static methods. Non-static methods can be called only by a reference to an instance. They cannot be used by a class name. For example (`getBytes()` is a non-static):

```
byte[] bytes = instance.getBytes();
byte[] bytes = ClassName.getBytess();
```

Static methods may be used with a name class as well as an instance reference. The last one is conceptually wrong, you should avoid such cases.
For example (`getBytes()` is a `static`):

```
byte[] bytes = instance.getBytes(); // think twice before use
byte[] bytes = ClassName.getBytess();
```

But the call of a static `getBytes()` looks strange, doesn't it? Static context knows nothing about instance variables and doesn't have information about the source *to get bytes*.

Answer (score 0):

*Concept:* You can only call the static members of a class using class name directly. But if it is a non-static member of class, you have to call it using a reference variable.

*Info:* `getBytes()` is not a static function of String class. So, it can only be called using a reference variable. You can find it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes--)!

*Explanation:* Your first way is correct and second one is not, since here you are calling it using class name directly.